# Creating variable amount of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, foreach

Thanks for reading.

I code an application that tries to close an application's all processes, if a process cant close normally after 60 seconds, it kills the process.

```
foreach (Process obj in Process.GetProcessesByName(application_name))
{
     logyaz("Waiting for " + obj.ProcessName + " to exit at " + DateTime.Now);
     obj.CloseMainWindow();
     obj.WaitForExit(60000);
}
```

this is where it waits for the process to close. It works perfectly fine.

But i want to implement something. I dont want to wait all processes one by one, i want to create threads as much as processes and shorten the waiting time.

I created threads before but it was hard-coded, i never created dynamic amount of them.

So what do you suggest me to do on it ?

Thanks for your possible help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to use parallel programing.

```
    Parallel.ForEach(Process.GetProcessesByName(application_name),
        (Process obj) =>
        {
            logyaz("Waiting for " + obj.ProcessName + " to exit at " + DateTime.Now);
            obj.CloseMainWindow();
            obj.WaitForExit(60000);
        });
```

Parallel is a static class which gives you opportunity of creating an easy to read multithreaded code. Thanks to this you can create not only parallel foreach loops but also for loops and save their results of executions.